# Mensagem de erro ao buildar apk em console Flutter

Tags: apk, build, dart, flutter

Quando tento dar um **flutter build apk --release** no meu app ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'C:\Users\Lucas Daniel\androiapp\android\app\Users\Lucas Daniel\androiapp\key.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
```

Porém o caminho pro arquivo está correto, apesar de repetir duas vezes na msg, não estou entendendo.
Esse é meu arquivo key.properties:

```
storePassword=lucas17
keyPassword=lucas17
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/Users/Lucas Daniel/androiapp/key.jks
```

E esse aqui é meu arquivo build.gradle:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.androiapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: `C:\Users\Lucas Daniel\androiapp\android\app\Users\Lucas Daniel\androiapp\key.jks` está correto ? Não faltou `C:` em `storeFile` ? ... `storeFile=C:/Users/Lucas Daniel/androiapp/key.jks`

Comment: Adicionei e o erro persistia igual, então fechei e abri o console novamente e obtive sucesso!!! Muito obrigado, esse erro saiu como um ponto e virgula num Debug, mas vou ficar mais atento, bom trabalho!

Comment: Se quiser colocar seu comentário como resposta vou te dar o upvote

Answer (score 1):

A resposta foi dada pelo @NoobSaibot nos comentários:

Faltava o `C:` no `storeFile`:

```bsh
storeFile=C:/Users/Lucas Daniel/androiapp/key.jks
```